# Find accounts without primary customer

Tags: mysql, sql

Let me update:

I have table example account with columns account_no, customer_id, is_primary,is_active.

Second table is called account_action, has next columns customer_id,action, date_action

So account can have multiple customers but one can be primary, I need to find all accounts that have active customers but don't have primary, so all customers on accounts are is_primary = 0, they are active and they dropped loan application.

In account_action table action can be null or can have 'drop' record in, if 'drop' is there action_date will have date when action is taken.

Which means customer example has removed loan application I have tried to group by account and use

```
Having max(is_primary) = 0
```

Function used above will not give me results that I want.

```
SELECT a.account_no
     , a.customer_id
     , a.is_primary
     , a.is_active
     , action
     , action_date
  FROM dbo.account a
  LEFT 
  JOIN dbo.account_action aa
    ON a.customer_id = aa.customer_id
 WHERE active = 1
   AND aa.action = 'DROP' 
   AND action_date IS NOT NULL
 GROUP 
    BY account_no
     , customer_id
HAVING MAX(is_primary) = 0
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Is there some sort of self referential relationship here? Is customer_id e.g. the child identifier and account is the parent? Does a row X in the table refer to another row Y that is also in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need both active customers and no primary, this should work:

```
select account_no
from t
group by account_no
having max(is_primary) = 0 and max(is_active) = 1;
```

Comment: note for DKCroat: `max(is_active)=1` is "at least 1 customer is active", `min(is_active) = 1` is "all customers per account are supposed to be active"

Comment: I have updated my question and added simple query similar that I used, I have changed to use functions above still I am getting records where account would have primary customer since in customer_action table will have just customers that have dropped from loan @Gordon Linoff